# VoiceOver reading hidden elements

Tags: html, voiceover, accessible

On the site I am working on we have 1) A mobile header 2) a desktop header. Both are loaded but images are lazy loaded + some of the desktop contents.

We are working on making the website accessible to blind people, I am testing with VoiceOver on Mac.

When I am testing it seems to want to read the mobile menu no matter what I do however.

```
<div aria-hidden="true" hidden style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <nav aria-hidden="true">
        <div>
            <div class="react-hamburger-menu" aria-hidden="true">
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

We need to render both because on a large tablet it will be the mobile header in portrait and deskt(ish) header in landscape mode.

I can't find anything else to make it stop reading this. It reads this deepest child still as a button and proceeeds to read the whole mobile menu (after I've gone through the whole desktop version)

**Edit:** I am using Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: `aria-hidden` is well supported on all browsers, platforms (mac and pc), and screen readers.  hiding a "parent" element will hide all the children.  note that using ARIA attributes is kind of a last resort (see the first rule of ARIA use - https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1).  if you can hide elements the "normal" way with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, that will automatically hide the element from a screen reader and `aria-hidden` won't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I had missed some elements that were moved using React Portal, also VoiceOver seems to **not** read only `display: block; visibility: hidden;` elements, and not really care much about `aria-hidden="true"`